# Convert Uinit8List to File in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hello I'm using [flutter_dropzone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dropzone) which gives me `Uinit8List` of the image. I know `dart.io` is not supported for flutter web.Instead I'm using [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) to get the file but I'm getting error

```
Error: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 0)
```

What i'm trying to do is get the file path and upload it to my chopper api([Multipart](https://pub.dev/documentation/chopper/latest/chopper/Multipart-class.html))

```dart
 Uint8List unit8List;
    uio.File createFileFromUint8List(Uint8List uint8list) => uio.File.fromRawPath(uint8list)
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Yeah are you trying to send the image from dropzone via multiform?

Comment: No, I am using https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper to crop a user selected image before passing it along to the backend. The `image_cropper` provides an implementation to get back the image as an `UInt8List` but on the web, I am unable to convert it to an `htmlFile`

Comment: did you figure this out? 

im using Image_cropper on the web as well. how do we send that as a mulitpart request to the back end? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `universal_io` package, but presuming that its `File` class behaves like `dart:io`'s:

`File.fromRawPath` expects its argument to be the desired file *path*, not the *contents*.  The path is expected to be a valid filesystem path and therefore must be in a valid text encoding.  `File.fromRawPath` is the same thing as the normal `File` constructor but provides greater control over exactly how the `File`'s path is encoded (e.g. whether a Unicode file path is normalized, and if so, whether it's fully composed or fully decomposed, and exactly how the Unicode path is encoded to bytes).

If you want to write a `Uint8List` as the contents to a `File`, you should use [`writeAsBytes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html)/[`writeAsBytesSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/writeAsBytesSync.html) instead. (Or alternatively `open`/`openSync` or `openWrite` if you need to do something more advanced.)